# Strange border in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting an odd behaviour with `UITableView` that maybe someone can help me with.

I have a `UITableView`. I then do:

```
table.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tablebg.png"]];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This works as expected, except I'm getting a strange white border along the right and bottom of the table (see image).

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you create the UITableView. Check the frame size and how its added to its superView

Comment: It's created in storyboard.  I'm not dynamically adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the tableview isn't aligned with the very superview (view) edge. Make it a bit wider and taller. I would temporarily set the view background color to something else so that you can see where the table extends to.

Comment: The white border isn't another view.  The table is created in storyboard.  I don't know where this white line is coming from.  If you squint and look very carefully, it looks like the cell separators run into the white line.  This seems to indicate there's something wrong with the cell, and not the table?  I get the same effect if I shrink the table or make it wider...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are using a PNG with alpha different from 0 and I have experimented the same issue with some images. Try:

```
table.backgroundView.alpha = 1.
```